# OAuth2 RoundCube

Tags: oauth, roundcube

Здравструйте.
Как можно сделать авторизацию с помощью OAuth2 для RoundCube?

Answer (score 1):

[oauth.net](http://oauth.net/2/) - на этом сайте есть множество библиотек для реализации Oauth2